# Can inscribe text into buttons in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter, mobile-development

I am trying to make keyboard like this

[image]

but instead I get this

[image]

Each my button is

```
class PinyinButton extends StatelessWidget {

  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  final List<String> titles;

  PinyinButton({this.onPressed, this.titles});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SizedBox(
      width: 30.0,
      height: 60.0,
      child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: this.onPressed, child: new Column(
          children: titles.map((title) => new Text(title)).toList()
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

and apparently each button or other container has some padding, which makes text to wrap early. How to remove this padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `RaisedButton`.

`RaisedButton` or `FlatButton` or `XXButton` are only about visual implementation of buttons.

What you want here is a simple `onTap` callback and then define your design yourself. Which is done by replacing `RaisedButton` by `GestureDetector` (and changing `onPressed` to `onTap`).